# Conjecture about natural number satisfying $ m(n)^k+1\space\mid\space n^{2k}+1 $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m(n)$ be the greatest proper divisor of $n$. Is there any number $n≥2$ not of the form $p$ or $p^3$ for $p$ prime that satisfies
$$
m(n)^k+1\space\mid\space n^{2k}+1
$$
for all natural numbers $k$?

I haven't found any of them, but I reduced it to the case where $n=pq$ for $p$, $q$ prime and with $p<q<p^2$. In this case, we must also have:
$$
q^k+1\space\mid\space p^{2k}+1
$$
But I didn't manage to break it further down; somehow the condition appears to be extremely hard to manage, although it seems pretty strong.

Comment: It is not immediate to me why you conjecture that they should all be of the form $p$ or $p^3$. Clearly the conjecture holds for all the $n=p$ for an odd prime $p$, but $p^3$? I would be grateful if you could elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @Giovanni De Gaetano: For $n=p^3$ the condition transforms into $p^{2k}+1\space\mid\space p^{6k}+1$ which is trivial because $p^{6k}+1=\left(p^{2k}+1\right)\left(p^{4k}-p^{2k}+1\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't $p^2$ the greatest proper divisor of $p^3$? If the definition were as you mean it, the conjecture would work for all the $n$ of the form $n= p^j$ for $j$ natural odd and $p$ odd prime. Is it right?

Comment: Ooops, now I see it. I missed a $2$ in the conjecture, 'sorry for the annoyance.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to answer the question :)

Comment: I checked (not very carefully) with a computer, there seem to be no $n\le140$ and $1\le k\le10$ (apart from $n=p,p^3$)  for which $m(n)^k+1\space\mid\space n^{2k}+1$. Is the question resolved if you replace *for all $k$* with *for some $k$*?

Comment: If the condition had only to be true for $k=1$, then there exist counter examples. The first one I've found is $31\cdot 73$. But as already in this case the smallest counter example is relatively big, it is possible that the conjecture is false, but the smallest could be huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is not prime then $n=pm$ where $m=m(n)$ and $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$. Then the condition implies
$$ m+1 \mid m^2p^2+1 $$
But
$$ m+1 \mid (m+1)(m-1)p^2 = m^2p^2-p^2 $$
hence
$$ m+1 \mid m^2p^2+1-(m^2p^2-p^2) = p^2+1 $$
and we must have $p^2\ge m$.

If $n\ne p^3$ then $m<p^2$. So $m$ cannot have two prime factors $\ge p$, but nor can it have any prime factors $<p$ since $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$. Hence $m$ must be prime.

Let $r>n$ be a prime with $\left(\frac{m}{r}\right)=-1$.$^\dagger$
Then by Euler's criterion
$$
m^{\frac{r-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod r \\
r \mid m^{\frac{r-1}{2}}+1
$$
But
$$
n^{r-1}+1 \equiv 2 \pmod r
$$
and hence
$$
m^{\frac{r-1}{2}}+1 \not\mid n^{r-1}+1
$$

Hence if $n$ is not of the form $p$ or $p^3$ with $p$ prime, then the condition cannot be satisfied for all $k$.

$\dagger$ Given $m$ prime we can always find a prime $r>n$ with $\left(\frac{m}{r}\right)=-1$. Let $b$ be any quadratic nonresidue mod $m$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem we can find $r_0$ with $r_0 \equiv 1 \pmod {4}$ and $r_0 \equiv b \pmod m$. Then by Dirichlet's theorem there is a prime $r>n$ with $r\equiv r_0 \pmod {4m}$, and by quadratic reciprocity
$$
\left(\frac{m}{r}\right) = \left(\frac{r}{m}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{m}\right) = -1
$$